# android stock inventory system

Tags: android, methods

I have an inventory system that reads from a file and you should be able to enter stock items in manually as well, the program reads from the file ok but wont add a new item in, as soon as you click the add button the program crashes

below is the log cat:

```
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     ... 11 more
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at com.example.assignmentfinal.EnterItemActivity.onClick(EnterItemActivity.java:141)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     ... 14 more
```

and below is the item class and the enter item class:

```
public class EnterItemActivity extends Activity implements OnEditorActionListener, OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{
private EditText et;
private EditText etP;
private EditText etS;
private EditText etN;
private EditText etSU;
private EditText etA;
private DatePicker dp;
private CheckBox cb;
private TextView tvSC;
private RadioButton rbE;
private RadioButton rbS;
private RadioButton rbU;
private Item item;
private TextView tv;
private TimePicker tp;
private Spinner spin;
String[] idItems = {"1253", "3965" , "3234", "9912", "3423"};
private boolean isNew = true;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_item);

    etP = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_plant);
    etP.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    dp = (DatePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.dp_inspection_date);

    etS= (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_stock_id);
    etS.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    etN = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_name_of_item);
    etN.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    tp = (TimePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.tp_time_inspection);

    tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tv_inspector_id);
    tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tv_inspector_id_value);

    spin = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.sp_spinner_in_id);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter inspectorSpinner = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, idItems);
    inspectorSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(inspectorSpinner);

    etSU = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_stock_units);
    etSU.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    rbE = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.rb_condition_excellent);
    rbS = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.rb_condition_statisfactory);
    rbU = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.rb_condition_unacceptable);
    tvSC = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tv_conditon_selected);

    etA = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_additional);
    etA.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    cb = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.cb_follow_up);

    //initialise the data if this is not a new student
    //get the student object to be updated
    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        isNew = false;
        int position = extras.getInt("position");
        item = ((ItemApplication)getApplication()).getItem(position);

        etP.setText(item.getPlant());
        etP.setFocusable(false); //can't update the name        
        dp.updateDate(item.getYear(), item.getMonth(), item.getDay());
        tp.setCurrentHour(item.getHour());
        tp.setCurrentMinute(item.getMinute());
        etS.setText((String.valueOf(item.getStockId())));
        etS.setFocusable(false);
        etN.setText(item.getNameOfItem());
        tv.setText(item.getInspectorId());
        etSU.setText(item.getStockUnits());
        tvSC.setText(item.getCondition());
        etA.setText(item.getAdditional());
        cb.setChecked(item.isFollowUp());

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.itemmenu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) 
{
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);

    return true;
}


public void onClick(View v) 
{
    //get the values for displaying in the list
    String plant = etP.getText().toString();
    int day = dp.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = dp.getMonth();
    int year = dp.getYear();
    int stockId = item.getStockId();
    String nameOfItem = etN.getText().toString();
    int hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
    int minute = tp.getCurrentMinute();
    String inspectorId = tv.getText().toString();
    String stockUnits = etSU.getText().toString();
    String condition = tvSC.getText().toString();
    String additional = etA.getText().toString();
    boolean isFollowUp= cb.isChecked();

        if (isNew)
        {
            item = new Item(plant, day, month, year, stockId, nameOfItem,  hour, minute, inspectorId, stockUnits, condition, additional, false);
            ((ItemApplication)getApplication()).addItem(item);
        }
        else
        {
            //update the student already in the list
            item.setPlant(plant);
            item.setDay(day);
            item.setMonth(month);
            item.setStockId(stockId);
            item.setNameOfItem(nameOfItem);
            item.setYear(year);
            item.setHour(hour);
            item.setMinute(minute);
            item.setInspectorId(inspectorId);
            item.setStockUnits(stockUnits);
            item.setCondition(condition);
            item.setAdditional(additional);
            item.setFollowUp(isFollowUp);
        }

        showItem(item);
    }

    public void showItem(Item i) 
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Item Details").setMessage(i.toString()).setNeutralButton("OK", this).show();         
    } 

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        tv.setText(idItems [position]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
    {
        tv.setText("");
    }

    public void onRadioButtonClickCondition(View view)
    {   
        if(rbE.isChecked())
        {
            tvSC.setText("Excellent");
        }
        else if(rbS.isChecked())
        {
            tvSC.setText("Satisfactory");
        }
        else if(rbU.isChecked())
        {
            tvSC.setText("Unacceptable");
        }
    }


}

public class Item  
{
private String plant;
private int day, month, year;
private int hour, minute;
private int stockId;
private String nameOfItem;
private String inspectorId;
private String stockUnits;
private String condition;
private String additional;
private boolean isFollowUp;

public Item(String plant, int day, int month, int year,  int stockId, String nameOfItem, int hour, int minute, String inspectorId, String stockUnits, String condition, String additional, boolean isFollowUp)
{
    this.plant = plant;
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
    this.stockId = stockId;
    this.nameOfItem = nameOfItem;
    this.inspectorId = getInspectorId();
    this.stockUnits = getStockUnits();
    this.condition = getCondition();
    this.additional = getAdditional();
    this.isFollowUp = isFollowUp();
}

public String getPlant() 
{
    return plant;
}

public boolean isFollowUp() 
{
    return isFollowUp;
}

@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return "Plant: " + plant + "\n" + "Inspection Date: " + day + ", " + (month +1) + ", " + year + 
            "\n" + "Inspection Time: " + hour + ":" + minute + "\n" + "Stock ID: " + stockId + "\n" + "Name of Item: " + nameOfItem + "\n" + "Inspector ID: "
            + inspectorId + "\n" + "Stock Units: " + stockUnits + "\n" + "Condition: " + condition + "\n" 
            + "Additional Info: " + additional +"\n" + "Follow-up? " + isFollowUp;
}

public Item(String plant, int day, int month, int year,  int stockId, String nameOfItem, int hour, int minute, String inspectorId, String stockUnits, String condition, String additional)
{
    this(plant, day, month, year, stockId, nameOfItem, hour, minute, inspectorId, stockUnits, condition, additional, true);
}

public int getDay() 
{
    return day;
}

public int getMonth() 
{
    return month;
}

public int getYear() 
{
    return year;
}

public void setPlant(String plant)
{
    this.plant = plant;
}

public void setDay(int day)
{
    this.day = day;
}

public void setMonth(int month)
{
    this.month = month;
}

public void setYear(int year)
{
    this.year = year;
}

public void setFollowUp(boolean isFollowUp)
{
    this.isFollowUp = isFollowUp;
}

public int getStockId() 
{
    return stockId;
}

public void setStockId(int stockId) 
{
    this.stockId = stockId;
}

public String getNameOfItem() 

{
    return nameOfItem;
}

public void setNameOfItem(String nameOfItem) 
{
    this.nameOfItem = nameOfItem;
}

public String getInspectorId() 
{
    return inspectorId;
}

public void setInspectorId(String inspectorId) 
{
    this.inspectorId = inspectorId;
}

public String getStockUnits()
{
    return stockUnits;
}

public void setStockUnits(String stockUnits) 
{
    this.stockUnits = stockUnits;
}

public String getCondition()
{
    return condition;
}

public void setCondition(String condition) 
{
    this.condition = condition;
}

public String getAdditional()
{
    return additional;
}

public void setAdditional(String additional)
{
    this.additional = additional;
}

public int getHour()
{
    return hour;
}

public void setHour(int hour)
{
    this.hour = hour;
}

public int getMinute()
{
    return minute;
}

public void setMinute(int minute)
{
    this.minute = minute;
}
}
```

Comment: What is line 141? I dont see an button being initialized in your code

Comment: int stockId = item.getStockId(); and the button is done in the xlm, is that i am reading the stockid as a string but its an integer if so how do i make the read an integer.